# Lang files not being used by fabric

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I have got 4 items working but even with the lang files in the right place, the names are still all broken.
the files are inside of src\resources\assets\cauldrons\lang\en_gb.json
with the contents being

```
{
    "item.cauldrons.gold-base": "golden base",
    "item.cauldrons.iron-base": "iron base"
  }
```

I am definitely on the right language in Minecraft, What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your lang file to en_us.json and check if you didn't misspell anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have '-' in a item/blocks tag, try replacing all instances of dashes with an underscore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).